# Need best JCR and AEM url

Tags: aem

I need to study about JCR and AEM. But i'm unable to find resources. Anyone send me the best related url?

Answer (score -1):

I guess, in all cases [Adobe docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3.html) will be the best resource to study everything connected with AEM. Here you can find introduction to AEM, best practices in developing using AEM and find a powerful docs about AEM

Comment: i need practical examples.